# Android gradle build dependency

Tags: android, gradle

Recently,I change my project structure from old version to android studio new structure,and there are serval models in my project.Now I meet a problem,each model or the third party library may dependency same jar, but they may dependency different version,but I want to let them use the same version jar in my final builded apk,otherwise there will be serval same jars in my apk.Does gradle support some plugin to help me finish my build purpose?

Comment: please check this http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: Post all of the `build.gradle` files.